# How does cron handle remainders in "every so often" jobs

Tags: linux, cron

If I do this:

```
*/9 * * * * /path/to/wotnot
```

At what times will the task run in two hours, starting at 09h00

Is it A:

```
09h00
09h09
09h18
09h27
09h36
09h45
09h54
10h03
10h12
10h21
10h30
10h39
10h48
10h57
```

or B:

```
09h00
09h09
09h18
09h27
09h36
09h45
09h54
10h00
10h09
10h18
10h27
10h36
10h45
10h54
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When looking at a range, you interpret it within only that column, so '*/9' within the minutes column means "list every minute, then select every ninth value". This selection resets at the top of the hour, so you restart at xx:00, xx:09, xx:18, etc every hour.

It can also be read as "every nine minutes of every hour", implying the reset at the top of the hour.

So the actual behavior you'll see corresponds to option B.

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to actually answer the question. Did you try this to make sure?

Comment: Within the past 10 minutes? No. Within the past three months? Yes, though not specifically at a nine minute interval.

Comment: Don't see why I would care when you did but only if. Thank you.

Comment: I've had former coworkers get pissy about "no you didn't test it, you're relying on your faulty memory!" in similar situations (of course, 5 minutes later they walk away annoyed after I prove that it still works), so I've formed a habit of hedging against that in advance.

Comment: Can't blame them too much, I've met plenty of people who think their 5 year old experience with a deprecated product makes them experts in a different product that somewhat resembles the old one.

Comment: I can blame them for that when I'm still active in systems administration.

Comment: I know, I'm more referring to people who think their knowledge always lasts forever, whatever it is. I understand where your colleagues are coming from perfectly, even if you may not be that way.

Comment: Yes, your previous comment about the start time also makes sense as to why this is.

Comment: The first step in testing is to ensure that you have the same brand and version as the customer (in this case Jesse). I don't see any clue here so far about what cron he's using. (It's likely Vixie Cron, and this basic feature is likely stable across versions of that program.)

Answer (score 22):

To confirm John's answer, `*/n` in the minutes column means "when the minute is 0 mod n".  Here is a `crontab` entry:

```
*/7 * * * *  date >> /tmp/foo
```

and here's the output:

```
Thu Jan 10 14:49:01 GMT 2013
Thu Jan 10 14:56:01 GMT 2013
Thu Jan 10 15:07:01 GMT 2013
```

Note the gap between the last two times is **not** seven minutes, because after nn:56 the next time `*/7` matches is `nn+1:07.

Yes, I'm aware those times are in the future (or they were when I posted this); I had to drive the system clock forward rather fast to get a quick answer.